# Installing Google Cloud Cli Fails Windows

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, windows-installer

Please see the below error this comes up when installing the Google cloud CLI on windows
both as a Admin and as a regular user

I am installing it for all users with Bundled Python and cloud tools for PowerShell both checked

I don't understand the error any help or references why this happens and what could be done to fix this would be greatly appreciated

Thank you

```
Downloading Google Cloud CLI core.
Extracting Google Cloud CLI core.
Create Google Cloud CLI bat file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
Welcome to the Google Cloud CLI!
Beginning update. This process may take several minutes.
This will install all the core command line tools necessary for working with
the Google Cloud Platform.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\connection.py", line 414, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 454, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 498, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\Msadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0oqwgmw3\python\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Msadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0oqwgmw3\python\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Msadmin\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp0oqwgmw3\python\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dl.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 308, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 285, in main
    Install(pargs.override_components, pargs.additional_components)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 155, in Install
    InstallOrUpdateComponents(to_install, update=update)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\install.py", line 197, in InstallOrUpdateComponents
    _CLI.Execute(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 1013, in Execute
    self._HandleAllErrors(exc, command_path_string, specified_arg_names)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 1050, in _HandleAllErrors
    exceptions.HandleError(exc, command_path_string, self.__known_error_handler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\exceptions.py", line 549, in HandleError
    core_exceptions.reraise(exc)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\exceptions.py", line 146, in reraise
    six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\six\__init__.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 987, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 807, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\components\update.py", line 125, in Run
    update_manager.Update(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 989, in Update
    install_state, diff = self._GetStateAndDiff(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 692, in _GetStateAndDiff
    latest_snapshot = self._GetLatestSnapshot(version=version,
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\update_manager.py", line 675, in _GetLatestSnapshot
    return snapshots.ComponentSnapshot.FromURLs(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\snapshots.py", line 175, in FromURLs
    data = [
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\snapshots.py", line 176, in <listcomp>
    (ComponentSnapshot._DictFromURL(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\snapshots.py", line 200, in _DictFromURL
    response = installers.MakeRequest(url, command_path)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\installers.py", line 114, in MakeRequest
    return _RawRequest(url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\installers.py", line 162, in _RawRequest
    return retryer.RetryOnException(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\retry.py", line 201, in RetryOnException
    exceptions.reraise(exc_info[1], tb=exc_info[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\exceptions.py", line 146, in reraise
    six.reraise(type(exc_value), exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\six\__init__.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\retry.py", line 182, in TryFunc
    return func(*args, **kwargs), None
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\updater\installers.py", line 192, in _ExecuteRequestAndRaiseExceptions
    response = requests_session.get(
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\transport.py", line 251, in WrappedRequest
    response = orig_request(*modified_args, **modified_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\requests.py", line 246, in WrappedRequest
    return orig_request_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\third_party\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dl.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)')))
Failed to install.
```

Comment: The problem: **SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED** for the site `dl.google.com`. That site is working. This means you have a networking problem on your machine. Are you using a proxy, antivirus, or something that can interfere with the Internet?

Comment: Hi john Thank you for the reply the thing is that when I go to the specified URL https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/components-2.json in the browser it downloads the file fine can a proxy etc. still be the issue?

Comment: Can you try to follow the step by step [install the gcloud CLI to Windows](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#windows), review all the prerequisite.